# How to understand `const LayerVector& currentLayers(anotherLayer);`

Tags: c++

```
 LayerVector anotherLayer;
 const LayerVector& currentLayers(anotherLayer);
```

I can not understand the why the reference `&` are used here.

EDIT:
My shame. I only know the reference could be defined in following way. The way above make me confused... Thank you guys!

```
 const LayerVector &currentLayers = anotherLayer
```

Comment: reference used... well do declare a reference. This is all I can tell from the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declares `currentLayers` as a **const reference** and initializes it to `anotherLayer`. This essentially means that `currentLayers` will be an alias for `anotherLayer`. It being **const** means `anotherLayer` cannot be changed via this reference, only read.